# Storage Spaces virtual disk showing as RAW instead of NTFS

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I have 8 disks in a Storage Spaces pool with a single virtual disk carved out of it. I recently re-installed the OS which WAS Server 2012 R2 but am now using Windows 10 Education edition with all the latest updates installed.

After the initial OS install, Windows 10 picked up the Storage Spaces pool no problem. I was even able to pull backed up files from it to restore some applications. I enabled features such as Hyper-V and others and rebooted several times. The virtual disk (mine is assigned to "S:") came back just fine every time.

I "upgraded pool" because it was an option and I didn't plan on going back to an older version OS. That seemed to go OK and I could still access the VD at this time.

Then I installed all the latest updates and rebooted. **This is where my issue started.**

I am no longer able to access the VD (my "S:" drive) though Manage Storage Spaces reports that the VD is OK. Checking the health through PowerShell also reports that health is OK.

Disk Manager thinks that the VD is in "RAW":

![a2xzdjf.png][1]

and not NTFS which is what it should say. CHKDSK knows it's in NTFS because it reports it as such when I run it.

This is what I get when I attempt to access the VD through Windows Explorer:

![WQeGU7U.png][2]

I click cancel on that, fearing I may lose data (if I haven't already) then I get this:

![wrVZhPb.png][3]

I have tried:

- Running `chkdsk` - Fixed a ton of errors but didn't seem to help
- Running `Connect-VirtualDisk` - doesn't seem to help

I've looked through the Event Viewer but don't see anything useful there but I may not be looking in the correct place.

I've purchased R-STUDIO and I can see all of my files still sitting there. I'm even able to pull them back to the "C" drive. I just ordered an external drive large enough for me to extract them to that before blowing this VD away unless I can figure out how to bring it back.

*Images removed because I don't have the "points"*